# Why does my STM32F7 only interrupt every 43 seconds?

Tags: c++, timer, stm32, interrupt-handling, hal

My goal is to have interrupt 38khz and toggle a LED, but no matter what I set as prescaler and period

```
static TIM_HandleTypeDef s_TimerInstance = { 
        .Instance = TIM2,
    };
void Hal::initTim()
{
    __TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();
    s_TimerInstance.Init.Prescaler = 96;                         // This does nothing
    s_TimerInstance.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    s_TimerInstance.Init.Period = 26;                            // This does nothing
    s_TimerInstance.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&s_TimerInstance);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&s_TimerInstance);


    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
}
extern "C" void TIM2_IRQHandler()
{
    HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&s_TimerInstance);
}
extern "C" void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOI, GPIO_PIN_1);     // Happens every 43 seconds for some reason
}
extern "C" void HAL_TIMEx_BreakCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim){}
extern "C" void HAL_TIMEx_CommutationCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim){}
```

When I flash it to target, the LED toggles every 43 seconds no matter what the prescaler and period is set to.

I must be missing something, but I can't figure it out. Anyone with interrupt experience that could help?

Comment: Since this isn't all your code, one needs to ask if HAL::initTim is actually called, and if there's other code re-programming your timer somewhere.

Comment: What is the System clock, and the source clock of the timer? (frequency)

Comment: It would help to see a little more of your code, especially the initiation of clock, interrupt and timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. Timers are super simple. You've just made it hard by using the cube.

```
__TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();
TIM2->PSC = 96;                           // prescaler (note that 0 is /1)
TIM2->ARR = 0xFFFF-26;                    // reload on overflow
TIM2->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE;                // overflow isr
TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;                 // enable timer
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
```

In the isr:

```
if(TIM2->SR & TIM_SR_UIF){
    TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;
}
```

As an aside. I like to reassure reset conditions on init.

```
__HAL_RCC_TIM2_FORCE_RESET();
__NOP();
__HAL_RCC_TIM2_RELEASE_RESET();
```

Answer (score 0):

Different project with STM32F469I-DISCOVERY but I followed Jeroen3's answer. I'm not sure where you would have the `__HAL_RCC`... and `__NOP();` code, but it worked without it. I calculated the prescaler and period to be some factors. For example to get a blink LED 1Hz I would have prescaler' * period' = timer_clock which I learned was core_clock/2.

So a core_clock of 180MHz and a desired interrupt at 1Hz would give

> (prescaler+1)*(period+1) = 180MHz/2/1Hz = 90M

which can be split into 9000 and 10000. I'm not sure about the prescaler but the period on a 16-bit timer can be no more than 2¹⁶-1. This means that the factors could not be 90000 and 1000 because 90000 is more than 2¹⁶-1. Neither could it be 900 and 100000.

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
    #include "stm32f4xx_hal_tim.h"
    #include "stm32469i_discovery.h" //Needed for LED

    /* User can use this section to tailor TIMx instance used and associated
    resources */
    /* Definition for TIMx clock resources */
    #define TIMx                           TIM3
    #define TIMx_CLK_ENABLE()              __HAL_RCC_TIM3_CLK_ENABLE()


    /* Definition for TIMx's NVIC */
    #define TIMx_IRQn                      TIM3_IRQn
    #define TIMx_IRQHandler                TIM3_IRQHandler

    void TIM3_IRQHandler()
    {
        if(TIMx->SR & TIM_SR_UIF){
            TIMx->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;
            BSP_LED_Toggle(LED2);
        }
    }

    void initTimer()
    {
        TIMx_CLK_ENABLE();
        //SystemCoreClock = 180MHz
        //PSC = 180/2/10000-1 = 9000-1
        TIMx->PSC = (uint32_t)((SystemCoreClock / 2) / 10000) - 1;// prescaler (note that 0 is /1)
        TIMx->ARR = 10000-1;                    // reload on overflow
        TIMx->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE;                // overflow isr
        TIMx->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;                 // enable timer
        HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIMx_IRQn, 0, 0);
        HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIMx_IRQn);
    }
}

#include "gui/model/Timer.hpp"

void Timer::init()
{
    initTimer();
}
```

Other inspiration: https://github.com/PaxInstruments/STM32CubeF4/blob/master/Projects/STM32469I-Discovery/Examples/TIM/TIM_TimeBase/Src/main.c